# Firebase - How to retrieve data and sort it to display in list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, firebase-realtime-database, leaderboard

To give you some context: my project is a game and at the end of the game you can enter your Name and "submit" it to a leader-board. When submitting it's going to send your name and your global score to the Firebase.

This far, I'm able to submit data but I'm having **trouble to retrieve it AND sort it by that global score** so that the **Best player goes on top of list** (which is the leaderboard).

I'm using this to create my li in my ul:

```
function gotData(data){

  var scores =data.val();
  var keys=Object.keys(scores);

  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    var k = keys[i];
    var name = scores[k].name;
    var scoreGl = scores[k].globalScore;

    $("#scorelist").append("<li class='scorelisting'>"+name+": "+scoreGl.toFixed(3) +"</li>");
  }
}
```

and this is how it looks like on my website:

[Leaderboard on website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47Xgf.png)

I've been looking at the .orderByChild() but I can't make it work. Here is how my data in Firebase looks like when submitted:

[Screenshot of my Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLLLZ.png)

Here's the link to my project: www.targetime.surge.sh